# Find matching element in list using delegate and lambda

Tags: c#, list, lambda, delegates

## Edit

My original question was not very clear, so I'd like to try to rephrase it now. Please let me know if I still miss the mark.

Essentially, I'm trying to return a new string, in which all substrings enclosed by brackets have been replaced by a string from an object in a list. As an abstract example, I want to do something like the following:

```
public class MyType () : IEquatable <Property>
{

    public string id;

    public override String ToString()
    {

        return id;
    }

    public bool Equals ( MyType other )
    {

        if ( other is MyType == false )
        {

            return false;
        }

        return this.id == other.id;
    }
}



List<MyType> listOfCustomTypes = new List<MyType> ();

return Regex.Replace ( originalString, "{(.*?)}", d => listOfCustomTypes.Where ( t => t.id == d.Groups[1].Value ).FirstOrDefault ());
```

The problem I've run into, or, error, specifically, is `Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type (System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator) because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type`.

I am assuming that it isn't allowed to use return types in delegates, or something, because I can normally access it's properties, or cast to string.

*I've probably still managed to jumble my question, so if it helps, my full project can be seen [here](https://github.com/AVividLight/SRoguelike), and the relevant file for this question is [here](https://github.com/AVividLight/SRoguelike/blob/master/Project/SRoguelike/Assets/Code/GameManager.cs) (specific line is 161).*

---

## Original Question

I'm trying to learn how to use delegates and lambdas, and in typical fashion, bit off more than I can chew. In the following code snippet, I define a class, which holds a list of classes. In another function, I'm trying to use a string to find a list item, and get a value from that item.

```
[XmlRoot ( "Replacers" )]
public class Replacers
{

    [XmlElement ( "Property" )]
    public List<Property> properties = new List<Property> ();

    [XmlIgnore]
    public static Replacers replacers;
}


public class Property : IEquatable <Property>
{

    [XmlAttribute ( "id" )]
    public string id;

    [XmlElement ( "Value" )]
    public List<Value> propertyValue = new List<Value> ();


    public override String ToString()
    {

        return id;
    }

    public bool Equals ( Property other )
    {

        return this.id == other.id && this.propertyValue == other.propertyValue;
    }
}



public static class GetVariable
{

    public static string FromUser ( string originalString )
    {

        try
        {

            //return Regex.Replace ( originalString, "{(.*?)}", m => Replacers.replacers.properties.FindIndex ( m.Groups[1].Value ) );
        } catch ( Exception e )
        {

            return "ERROR: Unable to find '" + Regex.Match ( originalString, "{(.*?)}" ) + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

The commented out line above is that I'm trying to figure out. How do I replace anything that matches the pattern {(.*?)} with a value from the list item of the same name.

Thanks for taking the time to consider my question!

TL;DR:

How do I iterate over a list using lambda, where the iteration returns the actual list item? As an example, I want to do something like: `Regex.Replace ( input, pattern, m => myList.Where(listItem.identifier == m)`. I don't feel like I've made my question very clear, so please ask, if you're confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
var foos = new[] { "aaa", "aba", "aca" };

var bars = foos.Where(f => f.Contains("b")).Select(f => Regex.Replace(f, "b", "d"));

foreach (var bar in bars)
    Console.WriteLine(bar);

// Output:
ada
```

Edit: I'll try to address your comment

A lambda is just a shorthand for a delegate (a typed-method).

You're probably accustomed to types like int, string, double, Animal, etc.

Well, just extend that notion to method signatures.

You can think of any method signature as being a type.

Here's a method that returns a bool, and takes an int as a parameter:

```
bool A(int i) { ... }
```

So the signature can be viewed as a type.

A lambda is a shorthand for this. Here's a lambda, that takes an int, and returns a bool, just like the method signature above:

```
(x) => x % 2 == 0
```

Linq extension methods (Where(), Select(), etc) all take some delegate type, or lambda expression.

```
myCollection.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Where(x => x > 10).Select(x => x * 2);
```

The beauty is you can keep chaining these extension methods, each one becoming an additional filter if you will.

Select() is special because it's a projection operation (it transforms the items in the collection). You can see it takes this odd parameter here:

```
Func<string, string> // or something like that, depends on the types in your collection
```

A `Func` is kinda like a delegate, but in a more generic sense. It's easy to understand. The first type arguments are the input parameters (think parameters of a method), and the last is the output (think the return type of a method)

```
Func<in, in, in, out>
```

Consider this:

```
// Here's a method signature
bool MyMethod(int a, int b)

// Here's a lambda of the same delegate type
(a, b) => a == b

// Here's a Func being assigned that lambda
Func<int, int, bool> func = (a, b) => a == b;
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced with delegates and lambda, so please excuse me if this is a silly question, but using the example you provided, how would I search f, using Contains, but with all of the matches of `{(.*?)}`? Essentially, rather than looking for "b", I want to search for every instance of characters enclosed in braces, and use that.

Comment: Thank you for explaining these concepts to me, having deeper knowledge of how delegates work (and what they are) will definitely help me understand how to use them! I'm going to spend a bit of time working on applying this to my problem, I'll be back to mark your answer as correct after that (holding off for now, in case anyone else has more good tips, or suggestions). Thanks, once more!

Comment: Cool, I probably didn't answer your question specifically (as I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for). and that's ok! Arming yourself with knowledge is far more important than collecting green check marks on a website!

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to figure out how to solve my question, using your advice!